# How to get Build Successes details including Associated Changes and Associated Work Items from TFS 2015 in .txt file? Which API should I have to use

Tags: tfs-2015

[TFS build successes URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNqAn.png)

I have to write AssocoatedChanges and Associated WorkItems in txt file after build success. Team foundation providing any API which will give build details response?

Comment: Did you start by looking at the REST API reference documentation?

Comment: I am following document and getting result. But not getting what I want.I added a pic here in question. When New version is created from the TFS web Interface, the process should also create and store a release mainfest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API to get build details including Associated Changes and Associated Work Items:

**Associated Changes:**

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version={version}
```

**Associated Work Items:**

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version={version}
```

Please see [Get build details](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-details) for details.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can use below PowerShell script to get the build details including Associated Changes and Associated Work Items from TFS 2015 in .txt file (Just specify the correct parameters):

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection",
   [string]$project = "0323ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$BuildID = "1",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password",
   [string]$FilePath = 'C:\temp.txt'
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#BaseUrl
$WITbaseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildID)/workitems"
$ChangebaseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildID)/changes"

#Response           
$WITresponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WITbaseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value
$Changeresponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ChangebaseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value


#Output the Associated Work items to a text file. 

$WITrequests = @()

foreach($WITrequest in $WITresponse){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WorkitemID" = $WITrequest.id
          "WorkitemURL" = $WITrequest.url
        } 

    $WITrequests += $customObject       
}

$WITrequests | Select `
                WorkitemID,
                WorkitemURL | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Width 200 


#Output the Associated Changes to the text file.

$Changerequests = @()

foreach($Changerequest in $Changeresponse){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "ChangesetID" = $Changerequest.id
          "Comments" = $Changerequest.message
          "Author" = $Changerequest.author.uniqueName
          "Timestamp" = $Changerequest.timestamp
          "Location" = $Changerequest.location
        } 

    $Changerequests += $customObject        
}

$Changerequests | Select `
                ChangesetID,
                Comments,
                Author,
                Timestamp,
                Location | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Width 200 -Append # (with -Append, the contents will increment to txt file )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you have Idea how can call this API from powershell script?

Comment: Andy, How to check field is available or not in powershell. For example, System.Assigned to is not available in workitem  when System.State is closed?
below is URL: 
      http://xxx-xxxx-006:8080/tfs/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/15090

Comment: @nitiparikh Have you resolved the issue by the updated answer? Any update?

Comment: Sorry Andy, I am still working. And will give you updates soon

Comment: Its working perfectly fine. getting response and able to loop those changes and write into .txt file.  Thank you very much for your support. It means a lot to  me.

Comment: I can not. Because I don't have 15 reputation. That's a reason I sent thanks message here.